# Quebra de Linhas em arquivo txt - Python

Tags: python, txt, quebras-de-linha

Estou com um arquivo seleciona as principais palavras citadas no código que preparei. Porem na hora de mandar para meu arquivo **.txt** ele perde a quebra de linhas que seria o mais importantepara este documento.

Código:

```
     f = open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\test.txt", "w")
with open(r'C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\Respostas.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        for word in ['(Cliente', 
'Anten', 
'COnhec', 
'ANUIDA', 
'ANUIDAD', 
'ANUIDADE', 
'ANUIDADE)', 
'anuidade,', 
'anuidade,vcs', 
'anuidade.', 
'ANUIDADES', 
'ANUIDADR6', 
'POUCOS(EMPRESARIOS']:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():

              a = (line.strip(), '¬', word +'\n')

              arquivo.write(str(a))
              break
arquivo.close()
```

Resultado:

```
('2701¬ SEMPRE QUE PRECISEI FUI ATENDIDO COM ATENAO', '¬', 'ATEND\n')('6913¬ conhecimento', '¬', 'CONHECI\n')('11607¬ Atendimento noturno. atencioso e competente !', '¬', 'atenci\n')('13286¬ OTIMO ATENDIMENTO', '¬', 'ATEND\n')('14747¬ E pq eu estou satisfeito . sendo Cliente.', '¬', 'Cliente\n')
```

Resultado Esperado:

```
('2701¬ SEMPRE QUE PRECISEI FUI ATENDIDO COM ATENAO', '¬', 'ATEND\n')
('6913¬ conhecimento', '¬', 'CONHECI\n')
('11607¬ Atendimento noturno. atencioso e competente !', '¬', 'atenci\n')
('13286¬ OTIMO ATENDIMENTO', '¬', 'ATEND\n')
('14747¬ E pq eu estou satisfeito . sendo Cliente.', '¬', 'CLiente\n')
```

Comment: Por que você não salva tudo na string antes de mandar imprimir no arquivo? tenta acrescentar um '\n' no arquivo.write(str(a)+'\n'), não sei se funciona assim em python.

Comment: na linha do `a =` troque o conteúdo pra: `a = (line.strip(), '¬', word)  +'\n'` e veja se funciona.

Comment: Laerte sua solução da erro sry =S
L. Falousk sua solução tb da erro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri também para este caso!

Linux = '\n'
**Windows = '\n\r'**

***Neste caso o código fica desta forma:***

```
     f = open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\test.txt", "w")
with open(r'C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\Respostas.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        for word in ['(Cliente', 
'Anten', 
'COnhec', 
'ANUIDA', 
'ANUIDAD', 
'ANUIDADE', 
'ANUIDADE)', 
'anuidade,', 
'anuidade,vcs', 
'anuidade.', 
'ANUIDADES', 
'ANUIDADR6', 
'POUCOS(EMPRESARIOS']:
         if word.lower() in line.lower():

              a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n\r')

              arquivo.writelines(a)                         

              break

arquivo.close()
```